# как получить возвращаемое значение из repo sync в shell скрипте

Tags: shell, sh

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно написать цикл для repo sync чтобы запускать его пока он не завершится успешно.
Попыталась написать вот так

```
while(repo sync() != true)
do 
repo sync
done
```

Но получается какая-то ерунда..

Comment: а каков признак [не]успешности? код возврата?

Comment: 'repo sync' это reposynс? или это что-то самописное?

Comment: @defrag, судя по всему имеется в виду команда *repo* для скачивания исходников из нескольких репозиториев Git, как это, например, происходит для Android.

Comment: until repo sync &>/dev/null; do :; done

Вообще не мудрено, что получается ерунда в том случае, когда вы пишете на неизвестном языке и надеетесь, что это будет интерпретировано верно конкретной программой.